# Passing object through react context provider, it says: objects are not valid as a react child

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I am trying to pass an object through context provider value in order to be able to use setter functions to mutate the central state.
this is the code:

```
export const StoreContext = createContext()

const Store = (props) => {
   state =  {
      user : {},
      page : "messages"
   }
   const setUser = (user) => {
      this.state.user = user;
      this.saveState();
   }

   return (
      <StoreContext.Provider value={{state}}>
         {props.children}
      </StoreContext.Provider>
   )
}
```

this is my app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  StatusBar
} from 'react-native';

import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import StackNavigator from './pages/StackNavigator';
import Store from './core/Store';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
       <Store>
          <StackNavigator />
       </Store>  
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

StackNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react'
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    StyleSheet,
    StatusBar,
  } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Login from './Login'
import Register from './Register'
import UserArea from './UserArea';
import Landing from './Landing';
export default function StackNavigator() {
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();

    return (
        <>
                 <NavigationContainer>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="UserArea"   screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false
  }}>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Login"
              component={Login}
            />
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
            <Stack.Screen name="UserArea" component={UserArea} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={Landing} />


          </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer> 
        </>
    )
}
```

and this is the error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {state}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: So what value is `props.children`?

Comment: this component is a wrapper, so I can say almost everything is the child of this one. the exact child of this one is my main StackNavigator component

Comment: can you share full code

Comment: I added the app.js

Comment: Can you console .log props.chidlren? I guess StackNavigator is not correctly initaled. Can you share that code too?

Comment: I just added StackNavigator.js @Domino987

Answer (score 1):

it turned out I was rendering the object directly in some of the childs!
I did that when I was testing context functionality with a string value, but I forgot to delete that when I used object.

thanks for your effort.